# how we set image size of caroselView when we scroll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have using Carousel View and show image in Carousel View. and i have also using Pich and pan in image when we pinch a image and scroll carousel view new image also zoom. how we set image size normal

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have create a Carousel View and create image inside a Carousel View and bind image with list of image when we pinch image and then scroll image new image also show me zoom. i want show image normally. actually i have create image gallery and perform all function. so please help @Daniel

Comment: @ChetanRawat some code of what you have tried would be useful and it would attract more users to help you.

Comment: Are the source of images from web or local machine? Usually we can use a customize scrollview to achieve the zoom function of image, but from what I tested, seems it effects the layout of Carousel View when zooming. Besides, I personally think that using a hover layout to show and zoom the image after clicking on the image item of carousel view should be more friendly since carousel view itself detects the swipe gesture, when we pinch and pan, it is possible carousel view moves to other items.